# .htaccess file is not working in nested directory but works in parent directory?

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating a small eCommerce website. I want to hide the query string parameters and want to replace them with the forward-slash `/`. For this reason, I have created the following `.htaccess` file structure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php?product=$2 [L]
```

This works in the parent directory `http://localhost/ecommerce/index.php?product=43`:

`http://localhost/ecommerce/43`

But if I copy this same `.htaccess` file in the nested directory `product` to access the item `http://localhost/products/product/index.php?product=43`:

`http://localhost/products/product/43`

It did not work. I cleared cache and cookie as well but still no luck. What can be the issue in my `.htaccess` file? Thanks!!!

Comment: I am surprised the ecommerce/ works as you describe. Using `$.php` suggests that it should go to `ecommerce.php?product=43` and not to `index.php?product=43`. If you change `$1.php?product=$2` to `index.php?product=$2` in the products/ directory, does it work as expected? the way it is written, it implies the existence of `product.php` instead of `index.php`.